# Add number of observations to grouped robust regression?

Tags: r, tidyverse, regression

Is there any possibilitiy to add the number of observations to a grouped regression using lm_robust? Ideally, I want the regression table to include the respective number of observations by subgroup.

I've seen that this works for several regression methods using `nobs(df)`, but in my case this did not seem to work. What I would like to have is a combination of the following code. Using `reprex()`, the regression throws an error. The code itself still seems to work though.

```
library(tidyverse)

data(iris)

iris |> 
  group_by(Species) |> 
  summarise(obs = sum(n()))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   Species      obs
#>   <fct>      <int>
#> 1 setosa        50
#> 2 versicolor    50
#> 3 virginica     50

example <- iris |> 
  group_by(Species) |> 
  do(lm_robust(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width, data = .) |> 
  tidy()) |> 
  filter(term=="(Intercept)") |>
  select(term, estimate, conf.low, conf.high, p.value)
#> Error in tidy(lm_robust(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width, : could not find function "tidy"

example
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>   Species    term        estimate conf.low conf.high p.value
#>   <fct>      <chr>          <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 setosa     (Intercept)    0.865   0.0396     1.69   0.0404
#> 2 versicolor (Intercept)    0.165  -0.548      0.878  0.643 
#> 3 virginica  (Intercept)    0.465  -0.456      1.39   0.315

nobs(example)
#> Error in nobs.default(example): no'nobs' method available
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `tidy` method for `lm_robust` objects, I don't think you can extract the number of observations from the tidy result (see `estimatr:::tidy.lm_robust` and `estimatr:::tidy_data_frame`; the `nobs` part of an `lm_robust` object isn't included in the items picked out by `tidy`).

But I don't think there's anything stopping you from getting the number of observations from the data frame itself? For example:

```
iris |>
  nest(data = !all_of("Species")) |>
  mutate(n = map(data, nrow),
         lm = map(data, 
                  function(d) tidy(lm_robust(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width, 
                                             data = d)))) |>
  select(-data) |>
  unnest(cols = c(n, lm)) |>
  filter(term == "(Intercept)") |>
  select(Species, n, term, estimate, conf.low, conf.high, p.value)

# A tibble: 3 × 7
  Species        n term        estimate conf.low conf.high p.value
  <fct>      <int> <chr>          <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 setosa        50 (Intercept)    0.865   0.0396     1.69   0.0404
2 versicolor    50 (Intercept)    0.165  -0.548      0.878  0.643 
3 virginica     50 (Intercept)    0.465  -0.456      1.39   0.315
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Z.Lin! Unfortunately, I get the following error message when replicating your code: `Error in !all_of("Species") : invalid argument type`. When trying to reproduce your code with my own data, I get the following error message: "Error in all_of({ : object 'XXXX' not found
In addition: Warning message:
Using `all_of()` outside of a selecting function was deprecated in tidyselect
1.2.0."

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Would the code run if you replace that line with `nest(data = c(...))` where `...` contains all the other variables in your dataset, other than the grouping variable?

Comment: Sadly that does not seem to work either.